# Creating a MethodInvoker function

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

So I have multi threaded my application.    I ran into this error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

My thread was calling a windows forms control.  So to get around this I used

Control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ControlsAction; }));

I am trying to figure out a way that I could make this generic method so I can reuse code and make the app alot cleaner.

So for instance, on of my invokes I do the following with a rich text box.

```
rtbOutput.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {    
rtbOutput.AppendText(fields[0].TrimStart().TrimEnd().ToString() + " Profile not   
removed.  Check Logs.\n"); }));
```

Another is with a combo box where I am simply setting the text.

```
cmbEmailProfile.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { EmailProfileNameToSetForUsers = 
cmbEmailProfile.Text; }));
```

Another example is again with a rich text box where I am simply clearing it.

```
 rtbOutput.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { rtbOutput.Clear(); }));
```

How would I create a generic function that could do this for me where I just need to pass in the control with the action i want it to do?

This is what we have come up so far.

```
private void methodInvoker(Control sender, Action act)
    {
        sender.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(act));
    }
```

so the problem is something like appendtext, it doesn't seem to like.

Comment: use an Action<T> instead of / with the delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static class FormsExt
{
    public static void InvokeOnMainThread(this System.Windows.Forms.Control control, Action act)
    {
        control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(act), null);
    }
}
```

And then using it is as simple as:

```
        var lbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        lbl.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
               // Code to run on main thread here
            });
```

With your original label:

```
        rtbOutput.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
               // Code to run on main thread here
               rtbOutput.AppendText(fields[0].TrimStart().TrimEnd().ToString() + " Profile not removed.  Check Logs.\n"); }));
            });
```

Comment: Ok so for Action act.  What if it contains text or anything like that.  will that work if I pass it in to act?

Comment: So that won't work if i need to use rtbOutput.AppendText(fields[0].TrimStart().TrimEnd().ToString() + " Email Profile set.\n")

Comment: @user1158745 it should do, you can just put that line in the anonymous function, but if you want to pass arguments along as well then it's a simple matter of revising the extension methods signature.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?  Can you give me an example using the append text?

Comment: @user1158745 You take the example you have there, and you put it where his `// Code to run on main thread here` is.  You change nothing else.  It works.

Comment: @user1158745 It won't, it's not a built-in .NET method you need to put in the extension class too the one I wrote called `FormsExt` and you need to make sure you add a `using` declaration to point to the namespace you put the class in.

Comment: Ahh I see.  let me give that a try.

Comment: ok i am abit new to creating extensions class's.  So i wrote the class FromsExt.  Saved it as a CS file.  how do i put it in as an extension class?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1158745 it's already an extension class, extension classes are implicitly treated as such based on convention, this might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I see what you mean.  howerver this function doesn't shorten the code up very much.  It's almost more worth it just to use the regular methods.